# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert Unix seconds to date and time from a csv file and tried to write the output to the csv file as a new column. I can convert and print the date and time but I cannot write it to the same csv as a new column.

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'

I tried to write in different ways but stuck. What am I doing wrong?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('C:/New.csv',sep=';')
print (df)

import datetime
import csv


for i in range(0,len(df)):
    row= df.iloc[i]['arrival_unix_seconds']
    a = int(row)
    date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(a)
    targetDate = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    #print(targetDate)
    #targetDate.to_csv("b.csv", sep=';', index=False)

with open("New.csv", "a") as inputfile:

title = ["id", "space_id", "arrival_unix_seconds", "departure_unix_seconds", "xml_id", "Arrival_time"]
writer = csv.DictWriter(inputfile, delimiter=';', fieldnames = title)
writer.writerow({"Arrival_time: targetDate"})
```

Sample data

> id;space_id;arrival_unix_seconds;departure_unix_seconds;xml_id;Arrival_time
> 2950;72729;1619808731;1619809039;22
> 320;16639;1612627087;1612628433;76
> 82;3408;1609751088;1609751723;7

Comment: As the name suggest, `DcitReder` is for reading. You need [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) for writing. Also, if working with pandas, look at `pandas.to_csv`

Comment: Thank you Buran, I have tried that but I am get a new error AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: `{"Arrival_time: targetdata"}` is a `set`, not `dict`.

Comment: Kindly suggest what can be done to make it as a dict. @buran

Comment: You probably meant `{"Arrival_time": target_data}`; what you have is a set containing a single string that *looks* like a key-value pair.

Comment: Thank you @chepner, but the result is not added as a new column in the existing csv file, but code runs fine without error. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `apply` it is way fast than iterating rows one by one

```
df['arrival_unix_seconds'] = df.arrival_unix_seconds.apply(lambda x: \
    (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(x))).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

# Save it like this
pd.to_csv('NEW.csv', index=False)
```

Instead of this

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    row= df.iloc[i]['arrival_unix_seconds']
    a = int(row)
    date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(a)
    targetDate = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    #print(targetDate)
    #targetDate.to_csv("b.csv", sep=';', index=False)

with open("New.csv", "a") as inputfile:

title = ["id", "space_id", "arrival_unix_seconds", "departure_unix_seconds", "xml_id", "Arrival_time"]
writer = csv.DictWriter(inputfile, delimiter=';', fieldnames = title)
writer.writerow({"Arrival_time: targetdata"})
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan Jain, but it shows an error  KeyError Traceback (most recent call last),

Comment: Can you add some sample data just 2-3 rows in question

Comment: id;space_id;arrival_unix_seconds;departure_unix_seconds;xml_id;Arrival_time
2950;72729;1619808731;1619809039;22
320;16639;1612627087;1612628433;76
82;3408;1609751088;1609751723;7

Comment: The data looks like this for 50M rows

Comment: Changed it now, Accept answer if it will work :)

Comment: Thanks Pawan Jain, but the problem is adding this result in the same CSV as a column under Arrival_time @Pawan Jain

Comment: Hey, @Aravinth sorry for the late reply, I updated the answer

Comment: Hey @Pawan, the problem is I need to save the calculated result in the same input csv file in the empty column "Arrival_time" Not as a new csv seperatly. Thank you.